# ¿Es posible saber si un usuario de mi web abre una URL específica con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Pasa lo siguiente:
Tengo un acortador de links que hace esta ruta (pagina de publicidad => URL destino), entonces me gustaría saber si es posible detectar cuando un usuario llega al fin de esta ruta o abre una pestaña/ventana con la URL especifica, en este caso saber si abrió una pestaña/ventana nueva con la URL de youtube.

He explorado con el objeto window y lo mas que he logrado es detectar el focus.

```js
setInterval( checkFocus, 200 );

function checkFocus() {
  var info = document.getElementById("message");

  if ( document.hasFocus() ) {
    info.innerHTML = "Tengo el focus.";
  } else {
    info.innerHTML = "Ya no tengo el focus.";
  }
}

function openWindow() {
  window.open (
  "https://youtube.com/",
    "width=640,height=300,left=150,top=260"
  );
}
```

```html
<h1>Detectando si la pagina esta activa</h1>
  <div id="message">Waiting for user action</div>
  <div><button onclick="openWindow()">Abrir youtube</button></div>
```

Comment: Afortunadamente, no. El JavaScript de una página no recibe ningún tipo de información de otras pestañas o ventanas del navegador.

Comment: Esto que quiere hacer es únicamente enlaces de Youtube o de otros sitios también?

Comment: Hola Richard, la idea es así, un usuario crea un anuncio con una img, title, description => el link lo acorto por medio de la api de https://exe.io/ => hasta aquí va bien la cosa, luego otro usuario que le click al anuncio, lo llevará hasta https://exe.io/ y luego de ver publicidad ahí, lo redireccionaría al link del anuncio que creó otro usuario(el link de destino). La idea es detectar cuando el usuario llegue a ese link de destino.